# how to do both inserting and deleting data from mysql using one php file

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working with Android Studio,
and using php and mySQL to use my data.

my table's name is 'laundry'
and it has columns named 'lmachine', 'lroom', and 'ltime'.

I used below code to insert new data to my db and it worked well.

```
<?php

include 'DatabaseConfig.php' ;
 
 $con = mysqli_connect($HostName,$HostUser,$HostPass,$DatabaseName);

if ( isset( $_POST['lmachine'] ) && isset( $_POST['lroom'] ) && isset( $_POST['ltime'])) {
    $lmachine = $_POST['lmachine'];
    $lroom = $_POST['lroom'];
    $ltime = $_POST['ltime'];


    $Sql_Query = "insert into laundry(lmachine,lroom, ltime) values ('$lmachine','$lroom', '$ltime')";
         
    if(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query)){
        echo 'Data Submit Successfully';
    }
    else{
        echo 'Try Again';
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
}


?>
```

in this php file, I want to add a query to delete rows which 'ltime' is older than now.

that query is **'delete from laundry where ltime < now()'**. I checked whether this query works (in phpMyAdmin console) and it worked.

I want to put that query in upper php file.

so tried this code

```
<?php

include 'DatabaseConfig.php' ;
 
 $con = mysqli_connect($HostName,$HostUser,$HostPass,$DatabaseName);

 if (isset($_GET['ltime'])){
     $sql = "delete from laundry where ltime < now()";

     if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
        echo 'Data Deleted Successfully';
     }
     else{
        echo 'Try Again';
     }
 }

if ( isset( $_POST['lmachine'] ) && isset( $_POST['lroom'] ) && isset( $_POST['ltime'])) {
    $lmachine = $_POST['lmachine'];
    $lroom = $_POST['lroom'];
    $ltime = $_POST['ltime'];


    $Sql_Query = "insert into laundry(lmachine,lroom, ltime) values ('$lmachine','$lroom', '$ltime')";
         
    if(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query)){
        echo 'Data Submit Successfully';
    }
    else{
        echo 'Try Again';
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
}


?>
```

and it doesn't work. I wonder if my approach was wrong or it's matter of syntax.

- ' doesn't work ' means... when I run a project using this php file in Android Studio, there's no error log, inserting data works as before but deleting data doesn't work. And the php file itself also works without any error message.

Comment: **Doesn't work** Is not a helpful description. What does it do? What does it not do? Did you check the Error log?

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: Why are you using `$_GET['ltime']` instead of `$_POST['ltime']`?

Comment: To get errors out of PHP _even in a LIVE environment_ add these 4 lines **temporarily, while debugging**, to the top of any `MYSQLI_` based script you want to debug 
`ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`. 
This will force any `MYSQLI_` errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
<?php
include 'DatabaseConfig.php' ;
 
 $con = mysqli_connect($HostName,$HostUser,$HostPass,$DatabaseName);

if ( isset( $_POST['lmachine'] ) && isset( $_POST['lroom'] ) && isset( $_POST['ltime'])) {
    $lmachine = $_POST['lmachine'];
    $lroom = $_POST['lroom'];
    $ltime = $_POST['ltime'];

    // Delete earlier data
     $sql = "delete from laundry where ltime < now()";
     mysqli_query($con, $sql);


    // Add new data
    $Sql_Query = "insert into laundry(lmachine,lroom, ltime) values ('$lmachine','$lroom', '$ltime')";
         
    if(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query)){
        echo 'Data Submit Successfully';
    }
    else{
        echo 'Try Again';
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
}


?>
```

Comment: Why should the OP ___try this___? **Good answers** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer. If it is well answered maybe they will UpVote it.

Comment: You also left the [SQL Injection vulnerable code in the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). Be careful, there are those that will downvote an Answer for that

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php

include 'DatabaseConfig.php' ;
 
 $con = mysqli_connect($HostName,$HostUser,$HostPass,$DatabaseName);

 if (isset($_GET['ltime'])){
     $sql = "delete from laundry where ltime < ".time();

     if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
        echo 'Data Deleted Successfully';
     }
     else{
        echo 'Try Again';
     }
 }

if ( isset( $_POST['lmachine'] ) && isset( $_POST['lroom'] ) && isset( $_POST['ltime'])) {
    $lmachine = $_POST['lmachine'];
    $lroom = $_POST['lroom'];
    $ltime = $_POST['ltime'];


    $Sql_Query = "insert into laundry(lmachine,lroom, ltime) values ('$lmachine','$lroom', '$ltime')";
         
    if(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query)){
        echo 'Data Submit Successfully';
    }
    else{
        echo 'Try Again';
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
}


?>
```